# Isit possible to add a heading to my code (involes writing in excel)

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have made my code to point where it writes the result in each cell in the excel file.

But however I'm having trouble with it, I want it to also write headings for example saying Name in B1 and then store the names entered in the code and also have a heading called Score in b1 and then the the output score below.

I have tried the same thing I done it my code for heading but wont work , any tips and help will be appreciated for a starting point.

```
if group == 'a':
    with open ('classa.csv','a',newline='') as student:
        foo = csv.writer(student,delimiter=',',)
        bar = [[name, score]]
        foo.writerows(bar)           

elif group == 'b':
    with open ('classb.csv','b',newline='') as student:
        foo = csv.writer(student,delimiter=',',)
        bar = [[name, score]]
        foo.writerows(bar)

elif group == 'c':
    with open ('classc.csv','c',newline='') as student:
        foo = csv.writer(student,delimiter=',',)
        bar = [[name, score]]
        foo.writerows(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the heading, you're on the right track. But you need:

```
bar = ['Name', 'Score']
foo.writerow(bar)
```

Additionally, you're going to have problems with:

```
with open ('classa.csv', 'a', newline='')  and
with open ('classa.csv', 'b', newline='')  and
with open ('classa.csv', 'c', newline='')
```

The arguments 'a', 'b', and 'c' are interpreted as the mode in which the file is opened. You either want 'a' for  appending or 'w' for writing, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the help , i added the line but when i did that it started to print score + name for every user's data stored in the file. http://i62.tinypic.com/2qiwweu.jpg

Comment: @ImYu , just remove it from the loop.

Comment: I might need help with that , since the code is going to be runned more than 10 times , im not really sure how to remove that function from the loop :(.